# Linux cURL JSON parse error - Expecting

Tags: json, linux, curl

Executing curl command on terminal throwing error JSON parse error - Expecting

```
curl -s -H "Authorization: Token 6e6d0ba76222c0ba0e8d515c24fae1f6c575f3ca" -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-type: application/json" -X POST -d ' {"text": "hello world","contacts":"f875c870-8df6-46e4-8748-e8d4c7ce0bce"}' http://XXX.XXX.XX.XXX/api/v1/broadcasts.json
```

ERROR

{"detail": "JSON parse error - Expecting ',' delimiter: line 1 column 17 (char 16)"}

Comment: There is a superfluous comma before `"text"`

Comment: Sorry actually there was one more parameter before text I removed that forgot to remove , . Still same error

Comment: Column 17 appears to be around the end of "hello". Do you have any (invisible?) special characters there that don't belong?

Comment: No invisible exactly same as that

Comment: I had a similar problem and had to perform a tr on the data to make sure there are no stray double quotes.

    FIELD =  'CONTENT " WITH DOUBLE QUOTES' | tr '"' "'"